# Calling activity method from extended view class in Android

Tags: android, view, android-activity, hierarchy

This is a problem I didn't forsee when designing the structure of my applicaton.

Basically i have 3 classes.

```
ProfileActivity //The main activity for the application.
ProfileView     //Which extends Linear Layout so that I can tinker with my own view. Note that this is just part of the whole activity and not the main layout
ProfileData     //This is just a class for storing data.
```

The activity contains multiple ProfileViews which each contain one profileData.

Heres where I'm stuck. My profile View has an on click method assigned which needs to call a populate method in the activity. Unfortunately ````

```
//I'm inside the activity
public void populateProfileDataForm(ProfileData pd)
            {
                //edit some text fields and other widgets from here
            }
```

Is there any way to call the activity method from the profileView class?

If not, then the error is in my design and can anyone point me towards a better solution for binding data, view and activitys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create a view, you always need a context, and always pass a activity to it.
So try use below code:

```
If(m_context instanceof ProfileActivity)
{
    ProfileActivity activity = (ProfileActivity)m_context;
    // Then call the method in the activity.
}
```

Or write an interface `onProfileViewClickListener` such as view.onclickListener. then the ProfileActivity implements it and set it to the ProfileView.

Comment: I don't think i understand context as well as i think i do. Just a quick question on this. The Profileview extends linearlayout. So context is passed as super(context, attrs);  So when I'm creating a profileView (in code, not xml) how do i pass the right context into it. IE getBaseContext(), getApplicationContext(), this.something()?

Comment: @OVERTONE Sorry i just left for a moment. Pass the activiy instance is well. You create the profileView in the profileActivity, so just pass `this` or `ProfileActivity.this`.

Comment: The way I was passing my context was wrong.... Your a lifesaver dreamtale. I've been stuck on that a while now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about if you assign an OnClickListener or OnTouchListener in your ProfileActivity Class and in this Listener you cann call the populate Method. In the OnTouchListener you can get the Position of the TouchEvent so you can assign it to a specific Profile.

Comment: So assign the onclick method to the main activity rather than the ProfileView class. This would be difficult as there are multiple instances of ProfileView and it they are also contained within a scrollview so manual positioning of the listener would be buggy at best